# Making IAP in iOS while there is no internet connection available

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

my title might be misleading but what I want to ask is if the user do not have any internet access while making IAP, is there any error returned from the delegate?

Currently I've implemented this delegate but it doesn't get called when the user tap to purchase IAP:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I handle this issue if the user try to purchase IAP without connection?
I would like to detect the error and show an Alert message to the user telling him that internet connection is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate delegate call for responding to failures with the restore process (which should return an error in the event of network failure):

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`

You should be requesting updated `SKProduct` information any time you show possible purchases anyway. There is a failure delegate method on SKRequest:

`- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

Otherwise, you need to use Reachability or something to determine if the user goes offline between showing the products and purchasing.

Sorry this doesn't better answer your question. I think the simple answer is "no". There probably should be one but it doesn't seem to be necessary under normal circumstances.

Comment: thanks, this is the one that I'm looking for
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error